# AMP page with Angular

Tags: angular, amp-html

Unlike Facebook's brainchild ReactJS, it appears Google's own javascript brainchild "Angular" is unable to produce Google AMP pages.

Has anyone here successfully produced a simple AMP page with Angular 7.2.4?